# Should an [employment-policy] tag be created?

Tags: feature-request, tags

A tag, [labour-policies](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labour-policies), was added recently through [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/76764/26455) (currently closed).

In researching what may be done with the tag, I discovered the following:

- Existing two-part tags use the singular "policy". Ex. [foreign-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-policy), [energy-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/energy-policy), etc.
- An [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22+employment+policy+%22%2C%22+labor+policy+%22%2C%22+labour+policy+%22&year_start=1985&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows a marked preference (more that 2:1 since the 1990s) for "employment policy" over "labor policy" and "labour policy" combined (and their plurals).
- The [employment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) tag has the following excerpt:

> Most governments track how (un)employed their citizens are, and often aim to craft policies to create employment. Use for questions related to subjects like unemployment numbers and general policies aimed at creating or destroying employment.

However, "general policies aimed at creating or destroying employment" would not seem to include general policies aimed at employer-employee relations at businesses and other organizations. (There are, for example, a [minimum-wage](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimum-wage) tag (13 Qs) and a [pensions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pensions) tag (25 Qs) for specific employer-employee policies.)

- Were an [employment-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment-policy) tag created, there would be few, perhaps four or five, questions with that tag. (A more intensive search may find more.)

The options for those particular questions are:

1. Tag with [employment-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment-policy).
2. Amend the excerpt for [employment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) to include a broader description of policies covered by the tag and add the [policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) tag to the questions.

---

My preference is to add the [employment-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment-policy) tag.

The proposed usage excerpt is:

> Questions about government policy regarding employer-employee relations, sometimes called employment, labor, employees' or workers' rights. See also, the [minimum-wage] and [pensions] tags.

Comment: What questions would this tag apply to as an existing question is needed to create a new tag.

Comment: @JoeW - The currently closed question noted in the first sentence would be retagged. Some others may be seen at [this list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bemployment%5D+polic*+-police).

Comment: I think it would be better to have a clear list of questions that you feel should be tagged with this new tag and that a question that was closed as being off topic isn't a good reason to create a tag.

Comment: @JoeW - Sure, it would be *better* to have a list and I have done such lists before; but there is a duplication of effort (on my part) and potentially hours spent researching and creating the list, which is why I won't do it again. Understand, I only expect four or five; but a more intensive review could reveal several more -- work I wouldn't do unless there is agreement to create the tag. While the list in the previous comment is only nine Qs, the broader search could involve hundreds of Qs. I am currently reviewing four lists (bookmarked searches) for retagging.

Comment: Based on what I see so far if I was to provide my feedback in the form of an answer it would be that I see no need to make this tag.

Comment: @JoeW - What about changing the excerpt for the [employment] tag? That's the other half of the issue.

Comment: Aren't tags created ad-hoc? You just type and create a new one. Here people would rather "work-policy".

Comment: @Trilarion - Yes, any user can create a tag when asking a question and that is what happened with [labour-policies]. One problem with ad hoc creation is that two or more such tags may refer to the same subject, thus making it more difficult to locate all related questions. When a new tag is added, I determine whether the tag is truly new, look for related Qs, and begin the process of retagging the related Qs. But the process begins with a tag name that is consistent with the site naming convention. Incidentally, "work policy" doesn't occur in an Ngrams search, thus not commonly used.

Comment: And there is the possibility to make tags synonyms of each other or to rename tags, just for completeness. Using the right tag name from the beginning is the best of course.

Comment: Another option would be to create both `employment-policy` and `labor-policy` tags, they are not necessarily synonyms of each other, there seems to be a distinction between _labor law_ and _employment law_ (see e.g. [here](https://curriculum.law.georgetown.edu/jd/employment-labor-law/)).